# getpgid not implemented with valgrind

Tags: c, macos, unix, valgrind

Considering this example :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int     main()
{
    int pgid;

    if ((pgid = getpgid(0)) == -1)
        perror("getpgid");
    else
        printf("pgid : %d\n", pgid);
}
```

When I'm running this program without valgrind, everything is going right, and the pgid is printed.
Whenever I'm using valgrind, `perror` will print `getpgid: Function not implemented`.

- Is it normal that `getpgid` is **not available under valgrind** ?
- Is there any **alternative to get the pgid of a specific pid** (excluding
  `getpgrp`) ?

I'm using macOS Sierra 10.12.6 and valgrind-3.15.0.

Comment: That's *weird*... What macOS version?

Comment: Added to the post

Comment: OT:  `getpgid()` returns `pid_t`, not `int`.  If `pid_t` is not really an `int`, you might be losing information - or wind up with negative "process ids".

Comment: Why not getpgrp?

Comment: @Topher Yes, `getpgrp` is available. @AndrewHenle The variable type do not change anything. pid_t can be an int typedef so...

Comment: @Topher I can't use getpgrp, it's for a bigger program where I fork, and I need to get the pgid from the parent process...

Comment: @rSim `pid_t` is not limited to an `int`. [POSIX specifies only this](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html#tag_13_67): "The implementation shall support one or more programming environments in which the widths of `blksize_t`, `pid_t`, `size_t`, `ssize_t`, and `suseconds_t` are no greater than the width of type long."  Note well that whether a `pid_t` is signed or unsigned is unspecified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem that valgrind could have some trouble to perform some syscall.

In the valgrind trace, I'm having :

```
--17135-- WARNING: unhandled amd64-darwin syscall: unix:151
--17135-- You may be able to write your own handler.
--17135-- Read the file README_MISSING_SYSCALL_OR_IOCTL.
--17135-- Nevertheless we consider this a bug.  Please report
--17135-- it at http://valgrind.org/support/bug_reports.html.
```

So I need to create a wrapper for the function, and it should work.
I will report the bug to the support.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't test via valgrind **on Mac OS X** because after Sierra, it is not supported. Instead, also it is what I do, install ubuntu via an virtual machine software then run valgrind.

macOS Mojave 10.14.6's `unistd.h` has the following part,

```
#if __DARWIN_UNIX03
void     encrypt(char *, int) __DARWIN_ALIAS(encrypt);
#else /* !__DARWIN_UNIX03 */
int  encrypt(char *, int);
#endif /* __DARWIN_UNIX03 */
int  fchdir(int);
long     gethostid(void);
pid_t    getpgid(pid_t);
pid_t    getsid(pid_t);
```

Rule of thumb, always try to be portable!

---

Incidentally, as @Andrew Henle mentions, `pid_t` can be of system-dependent type. But, it shouldn't be *unsigned type* to preserve portability since it can be returned as `-1` in the case of a failure. Moreover, on Mac OS X its type is `int`, as seen below

```
typedef int               __int32_t;
typedef __int32_t         __darwin_pid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
typedef __darwin_pid_t    pid_t;
```